# Cannot install Libtool library used but `LIBTOOL' is undefined trying to install ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, aac

I am trying to install ffmpeg on centos following this tutorial.

http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/CentosCompilationGuide

but when i run.

```
cd ~/ffmpeg_sources
git clone --depth 1 git://github.com/mstorsjo/fdk-aac.git
cd fdk-aac
autoreconf -fiv
./configure --prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" --disable-shared
make
make install
make distclean
```

I get the following error.

```
cd . && /bin/sh /root/ffmpeg_sources/fdk-aac/missing --run automake-1.9 --foreign
Makefile.am: C objects in subdir but `AM_PROG_CC_C_O' not in `configure.ac'
make: *** [Makefile.in] Error 1
[root@worldnewstranslate fdk-aac]# make install
 cd . && /bin/sh /root/ffmpeg_sources/fdk-aac/missing --run automake-1.9 --foreign
Makefile.am: C objects in subdir but `AM_PROG_CC_C_O' not in `configure.ac'
make: *** [Makefile.in] Error 1
```

I cannot get it to work for the life of me any help please why i maybe getting these errors.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using CentOS 5? Its versions of `libtool` and `automake` are too old. See [Libtool library used but `LIBTOOL' is undefined](https://github.com/mstorsjo/fdk-aac/issues/6). If you do not plan on encoding AAC audio with fdk-aac you can skip this step.

Answer (score 0):

hi i would like to say that to install ffmpeg we need a AAC audio  converter .this steps will be more easy and accurate to compile .the file which you were using doesn't contains all the compilation components here are quite easy steps

*libfdk_aac AAC audio encoder. Requires ffmpeg to be configured with
--enable-libfdk_aac (and --enable-nonfree if you also included --enable-gpl).*

```
cd ~/ffmpeg_sources
git clone --depth 1 git://git.code.sf.net/p/opencore-amr/fdk-aac
cd fdk-aac
autoreconf -fiv
./configure --prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" --disable-shared
make
make install
make distclean
```

full steps link is here https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Centos